# MultipartConfig in servlet api 3

Tags: java, tapestry, servlet-3.0

I have a [tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) web application which is configured by WebApplicationInitializer. Everything is OK, while you are not trying to set MultipartConfig in default servlet. The ServletRegistration.Dynamic which has setMultipartConfig() method is for creation, not modification. Is there a way to add/modify MultipartConfig in **default** servlet programmatically?